# MySQL and C : undefined reference to `_mysql_init@4'|

Tags: mysql, c

I'm trying to write a simple script for C to get values from a MySQL database, but it's throwing this error 'undefined reference to `_mysql_init@4''

Don't know if I'm not linking to something I should be? My C knowledge is limited...

I'm using Code Blocks on Windows, here's my code:

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <C:\mysql\include\mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   MYSQL mysql;
   MYSQL_RES *res;
   MYSQL_ROW row;

   char query[80];
   mysql_init(&mysql);
   mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","user","pass","db",0,NULL,0);
   sprintf(query,"SELECT src,dst FROM ipaudit");
   mysql_real_query(&mysql,query,(unsigned int)strlen(query));
   res = mysql_use_result(&mysql);
   while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
    printf("%s %sn",row[0],row[1]);
   mysql_free_result(res);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: script? Do you mean a "program" :)

Comment: `_mysql_init@4`? Are you perhaps compiling your code as C++?

Comment: Erm, I don't think so pmg...i'm not sure

Comment: Oh! `#include <C:\mysql\include\mysql.h>` looks wrong (but that's not part of you immediate problem). Try this instead `#include "C:/mysql/include/mysql.h"`: the backslashes may get transformed to something else and the forward slashes work as well.

Comment: Does anybody know how to link in Ubuntu ? Now i'm facing the current problem but I can't solve it. I guess I'll have to link in makefile.basic but don't know how to link. Pls help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined reference` refers to a problem with the linker. The function `mysql_init()` is not part of your code and is already compiled in a library. You have to tell the linker to include the code for that function by specifying the library where said code is.

I don't know how to specify libraries in Code Blocks, sorry

*Edit*

A quick Google search for how to specify libraries in Code Blocks returned a [interesting result](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/) :)

Comment: That website is great. Thanks for your help - problem now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

That's a linker error, indicating that the linker can't find the function `mysql_init`.

Make sure you are [linking to `libmysql.lib` or `mysqlclient.lib`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-client-compiling.html).  You also need to include `<my_global.h>` when building on Windows (see that same page in the MySQL Manual).

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your reply. I'm going to have to ask the dumb question. How do I link the libmysql.lib? With an #include?

Comment: In your Code::Blocks Compiler Settings, under Directories > Linker, add the folder where the MySQL libraries are located. Then in your project build options (Linker tab) add the proper libraries to the Link libraries list.

Comment: @Adam Maras:  Thanks a lot; I've never used CodeBlocks and as such had no idea on that one :-).  @logic-unit:  You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

use 32bit connector: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/ 
and dont forget to `#include <windows.h>` before `#include <mysql.h>`