# Error while connecting C program to MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, c

When I try to connect to my database I get an error :

> undefined reference to 'mysql_init@4'

```
#include<mysql.h>
int main()
{
  MYSQL *con;
  con = mysql_init(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

I use code blocks. What is the issue?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Is it a compiling error or linking error?

Comment: I think it's linking error.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Undefined Reference" to something implies a linker error. In this case you are possibly not linking to the right mysql C library. Link with the appropriate C libraries.

Also, a similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801017/mysql-and-c-undefined-reference-to-mysql-init4)

Comment: I tried that but it's not working

Comment: I uninstalled code blocks and again installed and followed the steps and worked! Thanks.